# Adding a module mapper to Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

The [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is/blob/master/tsconfig.json) has `paths` setup like this:

```
"paths": {
  "@fs/*": ["src/*"], 
  "@test/*": ["test/*"]
  }
```

With that all `@fs/blah/blah` imports are resolving fine in VSCode.  In order to get Jest to work with the same import declaration I added `moduleMapper` to `jest.config.ts` and this is the full config:

```
    module.exports = {
    roots: ["./src"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "@fs/*": ["src/*"]
    }
    };
```

With that statements like `import { isBoolean } from "@fs/is";` do not resolve.

When changed using a relative import it Jest does resolve it (`import { isBoolean } from "./is";`)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [jest document](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string), keys of `moduleNameMapper` are regular expressions. (not glob patterns)
And `<rootDir>` can be used to reference the root of the project. ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files))

So, we can configure like below:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@fs/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
}
```

Comment: I tried the expression but now I get the error ` TypeError: mappedModuleName.replace is not a function`

Comment: @Ole Sorry, my code was wrong. I edited the  code. Could you try again?

Comment: Also put in a feature request to jest for glob pattern support: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7240                       https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7185